# Mockery: Method does not exist on mock object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mockery, laravel-testing

So I have an object which I am mocking and it has methods that are used for sending emails.  I have gone from a static class over to a concrete class because I was having issues testing the static class with Mockery.

However I am now finding that when an eloquent model is saved it throws an event which fires off a listener.  This listener is what is responsible for kicking off the call to the mock objects method.

I have found that when I do something like the following it works.

```php
$model = factory(MyClass::class)->make();
$model->property = 'value';
$model->save()
$this->mailer->shouldHaveReceived('methodName')->with($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
```

It will fail every time complaining that the method does not exist on the mock object, the worst part is if I go into my listener where the mock object method is called and I do something like this

```php
echo '<pre>'.print_r(get_class_methods($this->mailer), true).'</pre>'; exit;
```

it shows that the method is in-fact in the array of methods returned from get_class_methods.

Now here is the kicker.  Everything works perfectly and the test passes without any errors if I do the following:

```php
$this->mailer->shouldReceive('methodName');
$model = factory(MyClass::class)->make();
$model->property = 'value';
$model->save()
```

Now I have been reading the [Mockery Gotchas](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/mockery/gotchas.html) and it would appear that if my class was calling a method that truly didn't exist on the object via `___call` then this error would be expected.

However my mailer class is NOT extending any other class that would have a `__call` method nor does it have that method defined on the class.

However as you may or may not know Eloquent Models do in-fact use the magic `___call` method.  However I am NOT mocking the model with Mockery, I am using factory models in Laravel but I am also not checking the model object for the method call, I am checking my concrete mailer class for the method call.

Anyone know why I might be getting this behavior from Mockery?

I am creating my mock object in Laravel 5.2 with the following code

```php
public function mock($class)
{
    $mock = Mockery::mock($class);
    $this->app->instance($class, $mock);
    return $mock;
}

$this->mailer = $this->mock('Namespace\Classname');
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating `$this->mailer`? In order to be able to use the spy functionality `->shouldHaveReceived`, you need to have invoked `Mockery::spy($className)` or called the `shouldIgnoreMissing` method after creating the test double with `Mockery::mock($className)`.

Comment: I have updated my post above to show how I am creating the mock object, though I have not seen anything regarding the spy method while researching this issue I will have to look into that.  I haven't seen anything other than what I have posted above (edited) meaning to add the mock to the laravel application via the instance method.

Comment: The problem is that the method does exist on the mock object and it says that it does not.